# how to import django project from github to local system?

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django.

I am trying to run a project, that downloaded from [github](https://github.com/mitar/django-mongo-auth) .

I run the **setup.py** file . that downloaded all requirements .

after that i am stuck because there is no any **manage.py** file  as i read in tutorial ( http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/setup.html) .

Comment: Not answer, but relevant to your question: Official Python package installation tutorial: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/installing.html

Answer (score 1):

That is not a project. It's an app that you need to install in your own project.

Comment: Any suggestion how i can add app in django project

Answer (score 1):

you have to install it

```
pip install django-mongo-auth
```

docs are [here](http://django-mongo-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html)

You should then add `mongo_auth` and dependency `django_browserid` to `INSTALLED_APPS`. Add `django_browserid.context_processors.browserid_form` to `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` to conclude django_browserid installation. Add `mongo_auth.middleware.LazyUserMiddleware` just after `django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware` in `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`.

Optionally, to use provided templates, you can add mongo_auth.contrib and sekizai to INSTALLED_APPS, and mongo_auth.contrib.context_processors.mongo_auth and sekizai.context_processors.sekizai to TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS, too.

Afterwards, you configure authentication providers you want to offer:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'mongo_auth.backends.MongoEngineBackend',
    'mongo_auth.backends.FacebookBackend',
    'mongo_auth.backends.TwitterBackend',
    'mongo_auth.backends.FoursquareBackend',
    'mongo_auth.backends.GoogleBackend',
    'mongo_auth.backends.BrowserIDBackend',
    'mongo_auth.backends.LazyUserBackend',
)
```

Hope it helps.